# Modifying a linked list to turn it into a binary tree

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, binary-tree, parent-child

Here's the format of a structure used to create a linked list:

```
struct LetterFrequencyPair
{
    char character;
    int frequency;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* next;
};
```

/ ********************************************************************************\

```
void createList()
{
    char c;
    int f;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct LetterFrequencyPair));
    printf("Enter the Character: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    temp->character = c;
    printf("Enter the frequency of the character: ");
    scanf("%d", &f);
    getchar();
    temp->frequency = f;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        struct LetterFrequencyPair* p;
        p = root;

        while (p->next != NULL)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = temp;     
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Above is the function that I wrote to create the linked list.

My question is how can I modify this function and structure to generate a binary tree instead?

I know that I'd have to change the structure to have pointers to a left and right child, instead of next. But I get stuck when trying to link it all up as there's two different directions to go. I've pasted my attempted modification below:

```
struct LetterFrequencyPair
{
    char character;
    int frequency;
    //Creating a pointer to point to the next child in the list
    struct BinaryTreeNode* leftChild;
    struct BinaryTreeNode* rightChild;
};

 void createList()
 {
    char c;
    int f;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct LetterFrequencyPair));
    printf("Enter the Character: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    temp->character = c;
    printf("Enter the frequency of the character: ");
    scanf("%d", &f);
    getchar();
    temp->frequency = f;
    temp->leftChild = NULL;
    temp->rightChild = NULL;

    if ((rootRight = NULL) && (rootLeft = NULL))
    {
        root = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        struct LetterFrequencyPair* p;
        p = root;

        while (p->leftChild != NULL)
        {
            p = p->leftChild;
        }
        p->leftChild = temp;

        struct LetterFrequencyPair * p1;
        p1 = root;

        while (p1->rightChild != NULL)
        {
            p1 = p1 ->rightChild;
        }
            p1->rightChild = temp;
    }

printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You choose left vs right by first deciding how you want your tree ordered. It's up to you. There's no predefined way. There are lots of binary tree schemes out there (e.g., balanced).

Comment: Binary tree is a data structure for sorted data afaik. If the data you want to insert is "greater" than the node you are on, you move on the right node, else on the left node. If the node is NULL, you insert. Could be optimised